# Is the ideal $(2,x^4+x^2+1)<\mathbb{Z}[x]$ maximal?, principal?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let I=$(2,x^4+x^2+1)<\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be an ideal.
>
> - Is $I$ maximal?
> - Is $I$ principal?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to use that $x^6-1=(x^2-1)(x^4+x^2+1)=(x^3+1)(x^3-1)$

Comment: Maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are of the form $(p,f(x))$, where $p$ is a prime number and $f(x)$ is irreducible modulo $p$. Can you show why? (for starters, take an arbitrary maximal ideal $M$, show that $M\cap\mathbb{Z}\ne 0$, and pick a suitable quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ that injects into $\mathbb{Z}[x]/M$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending the comment of Warren Moore, we see that for $p=2$ we have $x^4+x^2+1\equiv (x^2+x+1)^2 \mod p$. Hence the polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$; and the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is not a field, so that $I$ is not maximal. Regarding principal ideals, it could help reviewing the classical example $I=(2,x)$.

Comment: Note that $(x^4+x^2+1)=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ over $\mathbb Z$, so will be reducible for any choice of $p$.

Answer (score 1):

With your help, here is my solution:

> Let $p(x) := x^4+x^2+1$ a polynomial in $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$.
>
> $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I\cong(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]/(p(x))$
>
> $p(x)=(x^2+x+1)(x^2+x+1) \Rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is not integral $\Rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is not a field.
>
> **$\Rightarrow I$ is not maximal**.
>
> By contradiction, if $I$ is principal there is a polynomial $q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $(q)=I$.
>
> We must have $2\in(q)\Rightarrow \exists p_1\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $2=qp_1\Rightarrow$ deg(q)=0
>
> $q$ cannot be $0$ so $q=1\Rightarrow (q)=\mathbb{Z}[X]\Rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[X]/I=\{0\}$ which is a contradiction.
>
> $\Rightarrow$ **$I$ is not principal**.

Please, tell me if this is correct or if  there is mistakes.

Comment: Your decomposition of $p(x)$ only holds modulo $2$.

Comment: Yes, it's true, $p(x)\in(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I\equiv(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]/(p(x))$. Is there a mistake?

Comment: No, there is no mistake, I think !